# How to send User Properties to Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)?

Tags: google-analytics-api

With the Measurement Protocol for Google Analytics 4 we can send custom events ([source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/user-properties)). With the `gtag.js` Google Analytics, however, there are several [predefined user dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9268042) that GA automatically tracks.

That documentation page mentions:

> As long as you use the SDK or gtag.js, you don't need to write additional code to collect the following user dimensions from your mobile app and/or website.

However, how do we collect those user dimensions (like language, browser, country) with the Measurement Protocol? This is unfortunately not documented in the [Protocol reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference). (And neither could I find information on this elsewhere.)

### Edit

Here's an example of the JSON data that I'm sending:

```json
{
    "client_id": "xxx",
    "timestamp_micros": 1666280202293304,
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "params": {
                "event_source": "server",
                "page_location": "https://somedomain.com/page2",
                "page_referrer": "/page1",
                "page_title": "A test page",
                "ip_override": "xxx.xxx.xxx.0",
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; RMX1805) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                "debug_mode": false,
                "engagement_time_msec": 1,
                "session_id": "yyy"
            }
        }
    ],
    "user_properties": {
        "country": {
            "value": "US"
        },
        "device_category": {
            "value": "None"
        },
        "language": {
            "value": "en-us"
        },
        "platform": {
            "value": "web"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jos.  Sorry - I've edited your question, as I thought that it was one that I had asked that was very similar.  Sorry for the intrusion!  Feel free to edit it back.

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for looking at this question. I appreciate your edit since it improves the question. Hopefully this helps us both to get an answer! (Also thanks for your wholesome comment! :) )

Comment: From our perspective, we've given up on using the Measurement Protocol API unless it's for events that can't easily be done client-side (in our case things like refunds being triggered by a goods returned process).
We successfully controlled all events when using UA, but GA4 forces you to use client-side analytics to get anywhere approaching complete and reliable data.

Comment: I haven't made progress on this issue; I've shelved it until next month. I hope that in the month for the deadline, the API documentation is in better shape and complete (which it wasn't in April of last year).

Comment: I'll smack on a bouny to see if we can draw some attention, the docs seems to be the same as a while back

Comment: I didn't make progress on this issue despite a few full-time days spend. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/) mention Measurement Protocol is for use alongside automatic collection, which makes me think its limitations are by design. In the end I gave up and implemented the [minimal analytics](https://github.com/jahilldev/minimal-analytics) JavaScript library instead. Hopefully your progress has been better!

Answer (score 1):

Jos, there is now some documentation for `user_properties` syntax in GA4 Measurement Protocol payload. It goes alongside `client_id` and `events` definitions.

```
  const queryParams = `?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`;
  fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect${queryParams}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "client_id": clientId,
      "user_properties": {
        "customer_tier": {
          "value": customerTier
        }
      },
      "events": JSON.parse(events)
    })
  });
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/user-properties?client_type=gtag#example_usage

Comment: This is the format of JSON data that I'm sending via the Measurement Protocol, but when the message is processed the user properties (e.g. 'language') are ignored.

Comment: Hi Chrispy, thanks for the reply and thinking along! I'm not home but when I get back I'll try this new information.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and for me it is working. However I added the timstamp_micros to the event (there can be multiple events and of course this means the timestamp should not be set on the top level).

```
{
    "client_id": "1834292485.1697300633",
    "user_properties": {
        "user_role": {
            "value": "server"
        }
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "timestamp_micros": 1697905177065153,
            "params": {
                "event_source": "server",
                "page_location": "https:\/\/www.yourdomain.com\/page2",
                "page_referrer": "\/page1",
                "page_title": "Page 2",
                "ip_override": "xxx.xxx.xxx.0",
                "campaign": "your_campaign",
                "source": "your_source",
                "medium": "your_medium",
                "term": "your_term",
                "content": "your_content"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can test against the "/debug" API: https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?measurement_id=abc&api_secret=abc